# How to drop rows from a pandas dataframe based on a pre-made list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a big dataset. It's about news reading. I'm trying to clean it. I created a checklist of cities that I want to keep (the set has all the cities). How can I drop the rows based on that checklist? For example, I have a checklist (as a list) that contains all the french cities. How can I drop other cities?

To picture the data frame (I have 1.5m rows btw):

```python
   City         Age
0  Paris      25-34
1  Lyon       45-54
2  Kiev       35-44
3  Berlin     25-34
4  New York   25-34
5  Paris      65+
6  Toulouse   35-44
7  Nice       55-64
8  Hannover   45-54
9  Lille      35-44
10 Edinburgh  65+
11 Moscow     25-34
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `pandas.Dataframe.isin`. This will return boolean values checking whether each element is inside the list `x`. You can then use the boolean values and take out the subset of the `df` with rows that return `True` by doing `df[df['City'].isin(x)]`. Following is my solution:

```python
import pandas as pd

x = ['Paris' , 'Marseille']
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'City':['Paris', 'London', 'New York', 'Marseille'],
                        'Age':[1, 2, 3, 4]})

print(df)

df = df[df['City'].isin(x)]
print(df)
```

Output:

```python
>>>         City  Age
0      Paris    1
1     London    2
2   New York    3
3  Marseille    4
        City  Age
0      Paris    1
3  Marseille    4
```